# Bigcommerce API Java create shipment Error 400

Tags: java, bigcommerce

I am having issues creating a BC shipment against an existing order.

I am using Basic Authentication

JSON request is 
{"order_address_id":2,"items":[{"order_product_id":164,"quantity":1},{"order_product_id":124,"quantity":1}],"tracking_number":"abcd1234"}

code is as follows:

```
    String storeurl="storeaddress"+"/orders/"+BCordernumber+"/shipments";
    URL url = new URL(storeurl);
    HttpURLConnection httpcon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpcon.setRequestMethod("POST");
    httpcon.setRequestProperty("Authorization", encodeBase64());
    httpcon.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    httpcon.setDoOutput(true);
    httpcon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

    OutputStreamWriter put = new OutputStreamWriter(httpcon.getOutputStream());
    put.write(jsondata);
    put.flush();
    put.close();

    int result = httpcon.getResponseCode();
```

Any ideas would be great as to why I am getting this 400 error

Thanks
in advance

Comment: You'll have to check the logs on the server to see the stack trace and/or other message.  Without that it will be extremely hard to debug.

Answer (score 2):

I have realised my mistake, I was using the product_id rather than the order_product_id.

All good